# Expression String to string in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting this whole expression as String `(subCategory == "Serveware Sets") || (category == "Cookware & Bakeware") || (category == "Small Appliances") || (category == "Dinnerware & Serveware")`

Now I want to convert this string to the expression so that I can directly compare the values of the subCategory and the category.
How can I do the same.

Comment: are you asking how to parse it? then my question for you is, what's the grammar of your expression?

Comment: .. and what are these variables? What's their context? Are they Scala variables in your program or part of a DSL (e.g. DB column names, front-end related variables, ...)? Or it's related to Spark SQL maybe? Better to give more information in your question so that people can help you better. I guess maybe you have a fixed set of variables and you have an expression to parse, so it really depends on the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `expr`:

```
val filterExpression = """(subCategory == "Serveware Sets") || (category == "Cookware & Bakeware") || (category == "Small Appliances") || (category == "Dinnerware & Serveware")"""

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df
 .where(expr(filterExpression))
```

Comment: Well this is valid if the question is asked in the context of Spark SQL.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, I guess `||` symbol need to be changed to `or` string for the expr to work. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `||` symbol to `or` so that your expression becomes

```
(subCategory == "Serveware Sets") or (category == "Cookware & Bakeware") or (category == "Small Appliances") or (category == "Dinnerware & Serveware")
```

And then you should be able to use the `string` expression in *filtering* or *selecting* rows from *dataframes*.